# Vim: temporarily show only specific lines

Tags: vim

Sometimes, in Vim, I want to show only a specific part of a file (for example, a specific method) while hiding the rest.

This helps me to focus at the problem at hand.

I would like to do so without actually changing the file. Any idea on how to do this?

cheers & regards,
Klaas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to the already mentioned narrow plug-in, there's [NrrwRgn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075). Visual select the region, <kbd>:NR</kbd> and the window is split with the selected region isolated in the new window. Very useful for coding, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ESC>:help folding
```

Not quite up to speed on folding myself, but I believe that's the feature you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the vim narrow plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2097

VIM also has the ability to fold code, but that may not map entirely to what you want.