# Vim: Hide all code around selected code

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to be able to hide all code around the specific section of code that I am working with. Now I am wondering if this is possible in Vim somehow. I have experimented with it a bit already and have been successful at hiding lines above and below my selection by using highlight group Igore. This enables me to only see the lines that I want to focus on but the problem is when I begin to edit the code and add or remove lines. When I add a line or remove a line the already set highlight group Ignore is still maintaining the set line numbers so I either get to see some of the hidden code or some of the code that I want to see gets long and extends into the hidden line numbers. So I am wondering if there is some way to fix this or any other way to accomplish what I want in Vim?

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried Folding?

Comment: `:h fold-manual` read this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: temporarily show only specific lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979532/vim-temporarily-show-only-specific-lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding or shading parts of the buffer is not the Vim way. **Folding** is the built-in feature that comes closest. With `:set foldmethod=manual`, you can then use `zf` or `:fold` to hide the parts above and below.

For a plugin solution, have a look at [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075). It allows you to edit parts of a buffer in a separate scratch buffer, with automatic syncing back.

Comment: The NrrwRgn Plugin seems pretty close IMO

Comment: Wow! that plugin sounds as it might do the job for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To hide a range of lines (let's say from 1 to 10 and 20 to end, you can type `:1,10fo|20,$fo`

From there, you can create a function based on the current cursor position -10/+10

Note you have first to `:set foldmethod=manual` to make this works.

**EDIT:** a simple solution : `:1,.-10fo|.+10,$fo`