# Focus temporal buffer in vim

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

I would like to have the following functionality in the `vim` editor.

1. Select a certain text (e.g. paragraph)
2. Open a temporal buffer with only the selecting text (on full screen).
   The purpose here is to remove all the distractions and focus only on the selected chunk.
3. Edit the text in the temporal buffer
4. Close the temporal buffer with certain key, so that everything from the temporal buffer will replace the selected text in the initial buffer.

Is there already such a functionality in vim or such a vimscript?

Comment: See also [Vim: temporarily show only specific lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979532/vim-temporarily-show-only-specific-lines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for something called emacs calls Narrowing. There are is a Vim plugin that does this for you: Christian Brabandt's [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin.